# Include If else statement in docker file

Tags: docker, if-statement, conditional-statements

**I want to create docker file with conditional statements.** i get parameters from outside ( BUILD_TOOL) .
This is the code but i got error while building docker image.

i got this error =  *dockerfile parse error line 23: unknown instruction: ELSE*

```
RUN if [ "$BUILD_TOOL" = "maven" ] ; then 
    RUN mvn clean install;

#if build tool is gradle
else 
    RUN gradle clean;
fi
```

Comment: Dockerfiles don't have conditionals.  As @anemyte suggests and the linked question shows, you can `RUN if ...; then ...; else ...; fi` within a single RUN statement, and that's enough for what you show.

Answer (score 11):

Dokerfile itself does not have conditional statements. However you can implement them in shell:

```
RUN if [ "$BUILD_TOOL" = "maven" ] ; then \
       echo do something; \
    else \
       echo do something else; \
    fi
```

Just remember to add `\` at the end of each line when you have a multi-line command.

Comment: run command is not getting recognized if i put '\'

Comment: @TarangRathod you probably added one at the last line of the command. The last line should not end with `\ `, just as `fi` in the example.

Comment: I am doing something like this `RUN if [ "$zxbild" = "demo" ] ; then \
  RUN npm run zxDemo; fi` 
may be run wont work as you said it is shell way not docker way

Comment: Remove second `RUN` after backslash